# Safari app extension error "Inspection enabled ... for ... application with 'com.apple.security.get-task-allow' entitlement linked against old SDK"

Tags: safari-app-extension

I'm experimenting with Safari app extension (not Safari web extension) for the first time, and the template Hello World app that is created after setting up the Xcode project stopped working, I suspect after a macOS updates (current environment: macOS 13.5, Safari 16.6, Xcode 14.3.1).

I used to see a "Hello World" pop up after clicking the created extension button next to the title bar, but now no window pops up after clicking that button, and I also get the following errors/warnings in the console (extension is enabled in the Safari settings). I dabbled with settings, including changing the macOS deployment target and few code changes, but had no success. Any insight appreciated.

2023-08-05 14:26:40.027410-0700 WiFiScanSafari[41689:3961714] **Inspection is enabled by default for process or parent application with 'com.apple.security.get-task-allow' entitlement linked against old SDK. Use `inspectable` API to enable inspection on newer SDKs.**
2023-08-05 14:26:40.112121-0700 WiFiScanSafari[41689:3961714] Metal API Validation Enabled
2023-08-05 14:26:40.150825-0700 WiFiScanSafari[41689:3961714] [Window] Warning: Window NSWindow 0x1276046e0 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows.
2023-08-05 14:26:57.689198-0700 WiFiScanSafari[41689:3962335] [client] No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid